# Update Cursor ArcPy based on a separate feature class

Tags: arcpy, python, cursor

I am building a script that appends features from one layer to another however some of the fields that I need populated are not titled the same which causes them to stay null. How can I set the row in the update cursor command to equal the field from the original feature class? Code snippet below.

Original feature layer & field: mainLayer \ MainLineType

New feature layer & field: rLinesLayer \ FeatureType

Need to set "rLinesLayer \ FeatureType" (row[3]) = "mainLayer \ MainLineType" (circled in red)

[image: code snippet]

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange! As a new user, please [take the tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour)!  In the future, please include your code as a formatted code snippet, not a screen print.

Comment: if you want to append new features, you need insert cursor. And if you don't update a row value, it will remain the same, so you simply use row[3]

Comment: I am not appending new features, but existing ones from an existing layer to another existing layer. it is a tool to retire out old water systems from the "existing pipe layer" to the "retired pipe layer"

Comment: do they exist in the second layer ?

Comment: no, if they did I wouldnt have to append them?

Comment: so you need an insert cursor for the second layer...

Comment: using an insert cursor will cause there to be more rows than features on the map though. I am not trying to create new features. I have no issues getting the selected features to append to the new layer, just updating the single field in question

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand what you want to do. Maybe it is just my understanding of English, but it could help if you could edit your quetion and clarify what are  your input and output. I think that the confusion comes from the word "append" (in arcGIS, the append command adds new features to an existing feature class)

Comment: I assume based on naming that rLinesLayer is referring to the "retired pipe layer". Since these features do not at all exist on the retired layer, you will need to use InsertCursor to put them into the retired layer.  But there may be some confusion in what you are attempting to do. Please update your question to clarify.

Comment: the blank space thats circled in the picture where 'row[3]' is; I need it to be set to be equal to the value of a field in another feature layer, that is all. Everything else in the code works as I would like it to.

Comment: the append command is what places them into the retired layer (currently works). then update cursor is used to update the fields (currently works). I do not know how to set the row[3] parameter equal to another feature classes field value.

Comment: Have you considered using a JoinField (or AddJoin then calculate field) instead? The other option I see is to loop through the original feature class using da.searchCursor to get the value you that you want at the same time as you are iterating through the update cursor. May be tricky to be sure you have the correct row.  Or, I suppose, a searchcursor with a whereclause?

Comment: Also, look into field mapping options for the Append command.  http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/append.htm

Comment: It is still unclear what you are asking. Edit the question and explain why you cant use Append with field mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a two-stage process of append then update cursor, look into the Field Mappings option for the Append tool. The syntax may differ depending on your version; this is the link to the help page in ArcGIS Pro. Using Field Mappings will allow you to include data from columns that do not specifically match the new layer's field name.

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/append.htm

For your existing dataset (already appended, just need to update a single field): Try to AddJoin, then CalculateField. These steps can be done as part of an arcpy process, outside of the cursor loop.